# Recorrer Objeto, filtar por campo y hacer push javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo el siguiente objeto por ejemplo:

```
{
"name":"false",
"var_RadiacionGlobalInt":true,
"var_CO2InvVaisala":true,
"var_RadiacionExt":false,
"var_VVExt":false
}
```

Necesitaría recorrer ese objeto y los elementos que estén a true añadirlos a un nuevo array con un push. Este es el codigo que tengo implementado:

```
public guardar(){
    this.checkboxsensores = [];
    for (let variable in this.checkbox) {
        if (variable === 'true') {
            this.checkboxsensores.push(variable);
        }
    }
}
```

Necesito un formato final de esta forma:

```
["var_RadiacionGlobalInt", "var_CO2InvVaisala"]
```

No consigo realizar la búsqueda por el valor true solo por el nombre del campo, ¿como puedo filtrar por los booleanos?.

Un saludo.

Comment: tengo duda ¿qué es public?

Comment: Un metodo publico

Comment: los modificadores de acceso no existen como tal así en JS @Manolait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de Dev. Joel es mejor, pero para que entiendas lo que esta mal en tu codigo, tienes que verificar el valor de la propiedad y no el nombre de la propiedad misma.  Tu codigo corregido seria asi:

```js
var checkbox = {"name":"false","var_RadiacionGlobalInt":true,"var_CO2InvVaisala":true,"var_RadiacionExt":false,"var_VVExt":false};

function guardar(){
    var checkboxsensores = [];
    for (let variable in checkbox) {         
       if (checkbox[variable] === true) {
         checkboxsensores.push(variable);
       }
    }
    console.log(checkboxsensores);
}
guardar();
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución y la aclaración.

Answer (score 3):

Una opción sería emplear [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) para obtener las propiedades del objeto para  luego filtrar haciendo uso de [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) que creará un nuevo `array` con las propiedades que tengan el valor `true` `obj[el]===true`

```js
let obj ={"name":"false","var_RadiacionGlobalInt":true,"var_CO2InvVaisala":true,"var_RadiacionExt":false,"var_VVExt":false};
let arr = Object.keys(obj).filter(el=> obj[el]===true);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución :D